# retornando índices de listas python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tendo um problema na linha de `index`, pois não aceita `float`. Mas como eu posso fazer para contornar isso?

```
def median(numbers):
    numbers.sort()#The sort method sorts a list directly, rather than returning a new sorted list
    num = len(numbers)
    hlf = int(num/2)
    if num%2 == 0:
        m1 = numbers[:hlf]
        m2 = numbers[hlf:]
        un = int(m1[-1])
        pn = int(m2[0])
        middle_index = float((un+pn)/2) #int(len(numbers)/2)
    else:
        middle_index = int(len(numbers)/2)
    return numbers[middle_index]

test1 = median([1,2,3])
print("expected result: 2, actual result: {}".format(test1))

test2 = median([1,2,3,4])
print("expected result: 2.5, actual result: {}".format(test2))

test3 = median([53, 12, 65, 7, 420, 317, 88])
print("expected result: 65, actual result: {}".format(test3))
```

Comment: Não dá para entender seu problema. Qual erro que apareceu? Em qual linha? O que este código deveria fazer?

Comment: Não vejo como conseguirá retornar um float quando está contando o número de índices de uma lista, afinal não é possível se ter 4,7 índices, apenas inteiros.

Comment: este é o erro que aparece:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
expected result: 2, actual result: 2"

não dá para ter um índice quebrado, mas para este caso em especial precisamos fazer apenas a divisão entre a soma dos doi números do meio. quando uma lista tem um número par de elementos.

Comment: O que vc quer exatamente?

Comment: sempre que a lista tiver um número par ela deve retornar um float, que é a divisão entre os dois números do meio da lista com número de elementos par.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua intenção é calcular a mediana de uma lista:

### Com numpy:

```
import numpy
numbers = [1,2,3,4]
numpy.median(numbers)
2.5
```

### Sem numpy

```
def median(numbers):
    sortlist = sorted(numbers)
    len_numbers = len(numbers)
    index = (len_numbers - 1) // 2
    if (len_numbers % 2):
        return sortlist[index]
    else:
        return (sortlist[index] + sortlist[index + 1])/2.0

median([1,2,3,4])
2.5
```

Comment: solução muito elegante... muito obrigado. Estou aprendendo rápido com vocês.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você está tentando implementar a função de MEDIANA.

Nesse caso quando a lista de números possui comprimento ímpar você retorna o elemento central, mas quando o comprimento da lista é par retorna a média dos dois elementos centrais, correto?

Se é isso sua implementação deveria ser:

```
def median(numbers):
    numbers.sort()#The sort method sorts a list directly, rather than returning a new sorted list
    num = len(numbers)
    hlf = int(num/2)
    if num%2 == 0:
        mediana = (numbers[hlf-1] + numbers[hlf]) / 2 #Media dos dois elementos centrais
    else:
        mediana = numbers[hlf] #Elemento central
    return mediana

test1 = median([1,2,3])
print("expected result: 2, actual result: {}".format(test1))

test2 = median([1,2,3,4])
print("expected result: 2.5, actual result: {}".format(test2))

test3 = median([53, 12, 65, 7, 420, 317, 88])
print("expected result: 65, actual result: {}".format(test3))
```

Comment: uma parte funcionou Danilo, mas agora as listas ímpares não estão retornando os valores do meio.

Comment: Esquece Danilo, deu certinho... eu tinha esquecido de colocar a linha da segunda mediana. Valeu mesmo.